# Prove range of f',$\{f'(x),x\in X\}$ dense in $X^*$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach Space and let $f: X\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a Fre'chet differentiable function. Suppose that $f$ is bounded from below on any bounded set and satisfies

$lim_{||x||\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{||x||}=\infty$.

Then the range of $f'$,$\{f'(x),x\in X\}$ is dense in $X^*$.

I try to apply Ekeland's variational principle a s below:

Put $g(x)= f(x)+ \langle x^*, x\rangle$. Since $lim_{||x||\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{||x||}=\infty$, we have $f(x) \ge M||x||, \forall M>0$. Combine with  $f$ is bounded from below on any bounded set, we have $f$ bounded from below. So we easily prove that $g(x)$ is lower semicontinuous and bounded from below. But I don't know how to use Ekeland's variational principle to continue this prove.

Could you help me? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we apply [Ekelands principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekeland%27s_variational_principle) to $g$. Take $\varepsilon>0$ and any point $u \in X$ with $g(u) \le \inf g + \varepsilon$ (which exists by definition of $\inf g$). Then, we find $v \in X$, such that $\| u - v \| \le 1$ and
$$g(w) > g(v) - \varepsilon \, \|v-w\|$$
for all $w \in X$.
Using this inequality, what can you say about $g'(v)$?

Comment: Sorry for late response, because this problem appears in the section about Ekeland's principle, but I don't get the way to use Ekeland's Principle to solve it!

Comment: If have sketched the solution in my answer: Ekeland's principle could be used on $g$.

Comment: Could you please post detail your solution for this problem. THank you so much.

Comment: Do you mean details on the application of Ekeland or on the consequences of the inequality in my answer?

Comment: Application Ekeland for this problem. Could you post solution for this problem?

Comment: I have added some (trivial) details concerning the application of Ekeland.